# How do convert specific String format to DateTime in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this string '11:59 pm'. I would like to parse it as todays date and time.

```
String time = '11:59 pm';
```

I tried this: `DateFormat('HH:mm').parse(time)` and I get `1970-01-01 11:59:00.000` as answer which I believe is 'am' time and also the wrong date.

How do it get it as today date and correct am/pm type time? Thanks

Comment: use now() function

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: use `a` in your date format, which represent am/pm marker : `DateFormat('HH:mm a').parse(time)`

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Trying to read a from 11:59 pm at position 6` Got this error when format changed to 'HH:mm a'

Comment: Indeed, it must be uppercase, so simply make it uppercase before calling `DateFormat` : `DateFormat('HH:mm a').parse(time.toUpperCase())`

Comment: Sweet! Got it. Thanks. Second part is how to get DateTime of Today? instead of 01/01/1970

Comment: You can simply use the `DateTime` constructor and pass the year/month/day/hour from `DateTime.now()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `a` in your date format, which represents am/pm marker. See [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html).

Note that it works only if the marker is uppercase, so simply make it uppercase before calling `DateFormat` :

```dart
final String timeStr = '11:59 pm';
final formatter = DateFormat('m:s a');
final dateTimeFromStr = formatter.parse(timeStr.toUpperCase());
print(dateTimeFromStr);
```

If you need to set that time for the current date, one solution is to use the `DateTime` constructor and pass the year/month/day/hour from `DateTime.now()` :

```dart
final String timeStr = '11:59 pm';
final formatter = DateFormat('m:s a');
final dateTimeFromStr = formatter.parse(timeStr.toUpperCase());
final DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
final DateTime date = new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, dateTimeFromStr.minute, dateTimeFromStr.second);
print(date);
```